Execution of Liquibase in Java got stuck
When executing Liquibase 4.27.0 with
Liquibase liq = new Liquibase(path, accessor, database);
liq.update("invalidContext");

the first about 50 changesets are executed and then stops and hangs endlessly. Increasing log level to FINEST gives no more output. The process is started in a Maven plugin which starts an application which in turn executes Liquibase in a separate thread.
It took me some time of debugging to understand where the execution gets stuck. It is in the UpdateVisitor when calling
Scope.getCurrentScope().getUI().sendMessage("Running Changeset: " + changeSet);

which only prints the message to System.out.
It is quite unclear to me why printing a message to System.out should hang but when I comment the System.out lines Liquibase runs without any problem. I know that System.out.print uses internally synchronization and it seems two threads are blocking.
For me it is not clear why Liquibase uses two mechanisms to log messages, one is java logging and one is printing to System.out. This is inconsistent and furthermore, the System.out logging cannot be controlled and configured by the user.
